# Passing a Runnable object to a class extending Thread class and then starting it prints unexpected result

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I heard about an interview question from one of my friend.

What happens when we pass a Runnable object to an object of a class extending Thread class and start the class.

```
public class A extends Thread {

    Runnable obj;

    public A(Runnable obj) {
    this.obj=obj;
    } 

    public void run() {
    System.out.println("Printing A")
    }
}



public class B implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    System.out.println("Printing B");
    }
}


public class MainApp {
    public static void main() {
    B b = new B();
    A a = new A(b);
    a.start();
    }
}
```

Now it outputs **Printing A**

I was expecting **Printing B** as it is a perfect analogy to

```
Thread obj = new Thread(Runnable runnableObj)
```

Can someone please explain me this weird output??

Comment: This is not weird, this is expected. You instantiate an A, which you declare as an A, so that run() method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Thread has a `run` method which essentially calls `runnable.run()`. Except that in your class `A` you have overriden that method to do something else.

So `runnable.run()` is not called any longer...

Comment: It wouldn't be called anyway because the runnable is never passed up in a super() call in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an `instance of class A` (Now it is a `Thread`).

Then you are calling `start()` of that Thread `using instance a`.

You are just passing a `Runnable object as a normal instance variable to class A.`

There is nothing complicated in that.

**The result is normal**.

Answer (score 0):

With a tiny adjustment your code runs as expected.

```
public class A extends Thread {

    Runnable obj;

    public A(Runnable obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Printing A");

        obj.run();// <---- I added this.
    }
}

public class B implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Printing B");
    }
}

public void test() {
    B b = new B();
    A a = new A(b);
    a.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding the run() method on Thread and never pass the Runnable obj to super(). Try this:

```
public class A extends Thread {

    public A(Runnable obj) {
        super(obj);
    }

    public class B implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Printing B");
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A(b);
        a.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also find it instructive to add a run() method to A in the suggested like so:

    public void run() {
        super.run();
        System.out.println("Printing A");
    }
This will demonstrate what is going on in the default implementation of run() for Thread.